# Ethanol and water resistant adhesives

Tags: home-experiment, polarity

I need an adhesive that can bind to ABS plastic but is highly resistant to ethanol, isopropanol, and water. It's for use in an environment where it will spend a significant amount of time soaking in >95% alcohols, with agitation.

Temperature and pressure requirements aren't a big deal, this is for use at near room temperature and pressure. Strength requirements aren't anything crazy either, it just needs to survive light vibrations and light fluid flow. UV exposure is also a non-issue. However, I do need the adhesive to be watertight (where "water" = the solvents too).

My default is a cyanoacrylate-based adhesive but according to an incidental note on [this page](https://www.permabond.com/resource-center/cyanoacrylate-adhesive-environmental-resistance/) (emphasis mine):

> The bottom line is **cyanoacrylates have poor resistance to polar solvents** and better resistance to non-polar solvents.

So it seems like CA glues are out. What classes of adhesives could I use here? My gut says maybe a silicone-based adhesive, although I don't like working with those when possible (messy cleanup). Or maybe some type of epoxy adhesive?

Comment: I hope this question is OK here. I'm just looking for adhesive classes and types, not specific products.